# Why am I experiencing hard drive issues in 20.04?

Tags: hard-drive, 64-bit, ext4

I have four internal drives in my PC, Ubuntu 20.04. The first two are SSD drives, one for system and one for /home. Both of these are working fine.

The third drive is a Seagate Barracuda 7200.10 160GB HDD and was used as my backup drive. It was mounted at home/bob/mediaAccess to the drive was switched to automatic backups. These failed upon upon update to 20.04. I run the version with developer updates.

The forth drive is a Western Digital 640GB HDD and carried archive material.

The two SSDs are fine, both HDDs fail to work.

At first I thought the 160GB HDD had failed and replaced it with a new 240GB SSD drive. Ubuntu can see this drive, I have set it up with a MSDOS partition table and partitioned it with ext4 format. I cannot access this drive.

Clearly I getting something wrong here but can't figure it out. Any ideas?

Comment: Is the actual problem you encountered that the automatic backups didn't work?